# Registry - How to register Internet Explorer as a URI scheme and call from chrome?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, internet-explorer, regedit

In order to launch Internet Explorer from chrome in format `ie:https://example.com`, I have added the following registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie]
"URL Protocol"="\"\""
@="\"URL:IE Protocol\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie\shell\open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /K set url=\"%1\" & call set url=%%url:ie:=%% & call start iexplore %%url%%"
```

However, it works okay first time launching IE, but failed on the second time due to the double quotes in `url`(might be a bug for IE). 
[image]

I tried the following two ways to remove double quotes, but neither worked:

1. **Remove `"`**: `call set url=%%url:\"=%%`. This will cause the command to stop at `\"` and IE will not appear.
2. **Strip the first and last character:** `call set url=%%url:~1,-1%%`. Just doesn't change `url` at all.

So how can I remove the double quotes in a `cmd` script in registry? Or is there another workaround to launch IE in chrome(with minimum effort) ?

Comment: Hmm, your original strategy works for me. Could you please be more specific about what you're doing in Chrome that causes Internet Explorer to open with the misquoted URL?

Comment: @BenN I'm just calling `window.open('ie:https://www.google.com')` in javascript.

Comment: Could you try [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/faj08gse/)? It works for me consistently.

Comment: @BenN Thanks, same result. Opening the first IE is okay, but if I don't close the first IE window and click `Launch IE` again, the second IE window's url will be`http://%22https//www.google.com%22`.

Comment: Ah, my mistake - I hadn't realized the problem only occurred when one Internet Explorer window was still open. I've now posted an answer that fixes this for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like something is going wrong when Internet Explorer detects multiple instances and presumably tries to do something special in that case. There are [command-line options](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/general-info/hh826025(v=vs.85)) to control "merging" behavior, specifically `-nosessionmerging` and `-noframemerging`. When I supply those, I can successfully launch additional Internet Explorer windows.

Also, if you'd like the command prompt to go away after the launch, you can use the `/c` switch instead of `/k`. Applying these changes and cleaning up extra quotes from other values gives us this updated Registry file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie]
"URL Protocol"=""
@="URL:IE Protocol"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie\shell\open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /c set url=\"%1\" & call set url=%%url:ie:=%% & call start iexplore -nosessionmerging -noframemerging %%url%%"
```

Comment: Great solution, saved my day! I never know iexplore have these arguments.

Comment: Seems this works on Windows 10 but not on Windows 7.

Comment: @CDT Hmm, does the exact same behavior (mangled quotes on subsequent launches) reappear? Do the Internet Explorer versions match between the Windows 10 and Windows 7 machines?

Answer (score 0):

I used the following so that I can open file:// links in Chrome

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie]
"URL Protocol"=""
@="URL:IE Protocol"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie\shell\open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /c set url=\"%1\" & call set url=%%url:ie:=%% & call start iexplore.exe -nosessionmerging -noframemerging -extoff %%url%%"
```

For example:

```
<a href="ie:file://server/log/Log.mdb">Test</a>
```