# Force a url to open in IE from chrome without command process warning message

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, windows-registry, internet-explorer, command-line-arguments

My requirement is to open few urls on IE browser on cliking their links. So i have followed the below code to set the registry

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie]
"URL Protocol"=""
@="URL:IE Protocol"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie\shell\open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ie\shell\open\command]
@="cmd /c set url=\"%1\" & call set url=%%url:ie:=%% & call start iexplore -nosessionmerging -noframemerging %%url%%"
```

I am able to launch the IE window from chrome but with a warning message "Always open these types of links in the associated app" as below

[Chrome warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9UmP.png)

I have seen following links. But couldn't get away with this warning message.

[Registry - How to register Internet Explorer as a URI scheme and call from chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/1437499/registry-how-to-register-internet-explorer-as-a-uri-scheme-and-call-from-chrom/1437844#1437844)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40531374/open-internet-explorer-from-chrome-using-a-protocol-handler-ieurl
https://www.adamfowlerit.com/2015/05/how-to-launch-a-url-in-google-chrome/
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000317384&type=1&mode=1
http://jonas.follesoe.no/oldblog/2007-08-21-using-protocol-handlers-as-a-ultra-thin-layer-of-integration/

I believe /c will do the trick to get away the  warning message. But it's not working for me.

Is there any command line options to suppress the warning window?. Any help would be appreciated.