# Chrome - Is there a way in Chrome to set up a Bookmark that opens up a link in MS IE

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, bookmarks

For reasons still beyond me in 2019 (2020 by the time you read this most likely) three are sites that work well in one browser but not in others. I have a website that I can only use if I'm using MS Internet Explorer.

The browser I use daily is Chrome. Is there a way to set up a bookmark that will get windows / chrome to open up the link in MS Internet Explorer?

Or can I bind scripts (powershell, .bat, python) to a favorites tab in chrome? From there I can write a custom script to do what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best solution for you would be to use an IE URI. Looks like this other question has a similar topic, [Registry - How to register Internet Explorer as a URI scheme and call from chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/1437499/registry-how-to-register-internet-explorer-as-a-uri-scheme-and-call-from-chrom)

Comment: I can't change my computers registry at work but I'll try this when I get home this weekend. This looks exactly like what I would want. Thanks for introducing me to something new. I'll most likely choose your answer on Monday. Too bad I can't use it at work where I would need it, but I can't argue that this is the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

No practical way to open IE from a Chrome bookmark. You would need to copy the Chrome bookmark and paste it into the IE bookmarks so it is there when you need it.

Comment: Is there a way to execute a script from a book mark? The script would be stored on my HD.

Comment: Not that I have seen. That would be a programming problem. I have not seen a ready made program to do this